# Why does this java toCharArray statement only work sometimes?

Tags: java

I'm having problems with the following code.  Specifically, the 3 toCharArray statements.  When I first ran the code, it worked fine, but running it again, I get the following error messages for all 3 lines

> ']' expected
>   illegal start of expression
>   not a statement

I realize I can have it print the initials by just changing them to char[] and putting the [0] call in the print statement, but I'm curious why the code only works about half the time.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner names = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What is your first name? ");
        String first = names.nextLine();

        System.out.print("What is your middle name? ");
        String middle = names.nextLine();

        System.out.print("What is your last name? ");
        String last = names.nextLine();

        System.out.format("Your name is %s %s %s %n",first,middle,last);

        char[0] Finitial = first.toCharArray();
        char[0] Minitial = middle.toCharArray();
        char[0] Linitial = last.toCharArray();

        System.out.format("Your initials are %c %c %c",Finitial,Minitial,Linitial);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return type of `toCharArray()` -- does it match what you declare on the left hand sode in those three lines? Is `char[0]` a valid type declaration for a field/variable/etc. in Java?

Comment: The code as presented can not work. What's `char[0]`?

Comment: (`.charAt(0)` would be better in this particular case. Or better, `.codePointAt(0)`.)

Answer (score 4):

`char[0]` isn't a valid type for the `Finitial` variable. The only time you get something like `char[0]` is in:

```
char[] x = new char[0];
```

Instead, you should use:

```
char firstInitial = first.toCharArray()[0];
// etc
```

Or in two stages:

```
char[] firstArray = first.toCharArray();
char firstInitial = firstArray[0];
```

Comment: Helped me on an unrelated project, the toCharArray()[0]; caught me out. Thanks so much for a great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is illegal syntax:

```
char[0] Finitial = first.toCharArray();
char[0] Minitial = middle.toCharArray();
char[0] Linitial = last.toCharArray();
```

You want his instead:

```
char Finitial = first.toCharArray()[0];
char Minitial = middle.toCharArray()[0];
char Linitial = last.toCharArray()[0];
```

BTW: Java naming conventions demand that you start your local variable names with a lowercase letter. Use camel case like this:

```
char firstInitial = first.toCharArray()[0];
char middleInitial = middle.toCharArray()[0];
char lastInitial = last.toCharArray()[0];
```